# Where did my cloudbuild.yaml come from? And why does it error with a Dockerfile?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build, cloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to configure cloud run to deploy continuously from Github.

My repo uses a Dockerfile.

This worked fine in one project, we will call project A, now I am trying to recreate this in another project, we will call project B.

When I try to choose "Dockerfile" as my trigger. It says:

```
Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: if 'build.service_account' is specified, the build must either (a) specify 'build.logs_bucket', (b) use the REGIONAL_USER_OWNED_BUCKET build.options.default_logs_bucket_behavior option, or (c) use either CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY / NONE logging options
```

When I google this error I see comments saying to edit the cloudbuild.yaml file to set the options for CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY, however, I don't have a cloudbuild.yaml.

If I uncheck "send logs to github" it will succeed to build but then not deploy for some reason. It does not give an error.

When I go back to look at my cloud run for the project in project A that IS working, I see that when I edit the continuous deployment trigger, instead of specifying "Dockerfile" as the build file  like I specified when I created it, it now specifies cloudbuild.yaml inline, and in the inline cloudbuild.yaml I see a fully generated config file that I did not write.

So somehow Google generated this file for me.

So I have basically a couple questions:

1. **Where did that cloudbuild.yaml come from?** I didn't write it, how was it created?
2. How do I get Google to generate that file for me again in project B? What did I do the first time in project A that somehow created this file for me so I can replicate that process in Project B? I would copy-paste this file, but that would not work because the cloudbuild.yaml file that Google generated for me somehow contains a bunch of substitution arguments in it that I cannot provide.

Tried deploying using autodetect the config file and type, tried with Dockerfile specified, tried specifying cloudbuild.yaml file and then editing it inline and copy pasting the working one, but this doesn't work because it requires substitution arguments that include long generated IDs that I don't know how to provide.

Answer (score -1):

The `cloudbuild.yaml` file is a configuration file that is used by Cloud Build to specify how to build and deploy your application. When you create a Cloud Build trigger, Cloud Build will automatically generate a `cloudbuild.yaml` file for you. This file will include the necessary steps to build and deploy your application based on the information you provide when you create the trigger.

In your case, when you created the Cloud Build trigger in project A, Cloud Build generated a `cloudbuild.yaml` file that included the necessary steps to build your application using the Dockerfile in your repository. This is why you were able to successfully build and deploy your application in project A.

When you tried to create a Cloud Build trigger in project B, Cloud Build did not generate a `cloudbuild.yaml` file because you did not provide any information about how to build your application. As a result, Cloud Build was not able to determine how to build your application and the build failed.

To get Cloud Build to generate a `cloudbuild.yaml` file for you in project B, you need to provide Cloud Build with some information about how to build your application. You can do this by specifying the `build_config` field in the Cloud Build trigger configuration. The `build_config` field can be used to specify the location of a `cloudbuild.yaml` file or to provide inline Cloud Build configuration.

For example, if you have a `cloudbuild.yaml` file in your repository, you can specify the location of the file in the `build_config` field as follows:

```
build_config:
  location: 'cloudbuild.yaml'
```

Alternatively, you can provide inline Cloud Build configuration in the `build_config` field as follows:

```
build_config:
  steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image', '.']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image']
  images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image'
```

Once you have provided Cloud Build with some information about how to build your application, Cloud Build will be able to generate a `cloudbuild.yaml` file for you.

In your case, you can copy the `cloudbuild.yaml` file from project A and use it in project B. However, you will need to replace the substitution arguments in the file with the appropriate values for project B. For example, you will need to replace the `$PROJECT_ID` substitution argument with the project ID for project B.

Once you have replaced the substitution arguments, you can use the `cloudbuild.yaml` file to create a Cloud Build trigger in project B. The Cloud Build trigger will use the `cloudbuild.yaml` file to build and deploy your application.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: This is helpful, but for the _TRIGGER_ID value, I'm not sure what to put there. I see trigger name in the UI, but trigger ID is not specified anywhere for existing triggers.

Comment: This appears to be AI-generated content, which is currently [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/17011606) on Stack Overflow.